# Is the amount of health I heal from a hacked pack related to Sombra's charge gain

Tags: overwatch

Does it matter if I heal 1 health, or 250 health in relation to Sombra's ultimate charge rate? Would she receive the same amount of charge in both cases ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that her hacked health packs earn you [ult charge](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ultimate_ability) rate the same way that Soldier 76 and Ana do. That is **1 point of ult charge for every 1 point of health healed**.

> - "Heroes gain 1 charge for every 1 point of self-healing done.
> - Soldier: 76, Ana, and Sombra gain 1 charge for every 1 point of
>     healing."

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that Sombra ult requires 1250 points for a full charge.

Answer (score 2):

As with any other character capable of healing others, the amount of ultimate charge gained depends on the amount of health healed.

Answer (score 2):

As of the patch on February 27, 2018, Sombra no longer gains any ultimate charge by having teammates collect hacked health packs.